# Optimize Query with Joins + Where

Tags: mysql, optimization, phpmyadmin

I have a database with 11 tables and a total count of ~120k rows. I do the following query, to get the data of all tables:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
           char.id, char.firstname, char.lastname, char.commonname, 
           char.picture, nation.id AS nationId, nation.name AS nationName,
           nation.logo AS nationLogo, club.id AS clubId, club.name AS clubName, 
           club.logo AS clubLogo, league.id AS leagueId, league.name AS leagueName, 
           league.logo AS leagueLogo, card.name, char.rating, char.position, 
           pac.pace, sho.shooting, pas.passing, dri.dribbling, def.defending, 
           phy.physical, char.skill, char.weakfoot, char.quality, char.url
FROM       `characteristics` AS `char`
INNER JOIN `nation` AS `nation` 
ON         `nation`.`id` = `char`.`nation`
INNER JOIN `club` AS `club` 
ON         `club`.`id` = `char`.`club`
INNER JOIN `league` AS `league` 
ON         `league`.`id` = `char`.`league`
INNER JOIN `card` AS `card` 
ON         `card`.`id` = `char`.`color`
INNER JOIN `pace` AS `pac` 
ON         `pac`.`id` = `char`.`id`
INNER JOIN `shooting` AS `sho` 
ON         `sho`.`id` = `char`.`id`
INNER JOIN `passing` AS `pas` 
ON         `pas`.`id` = `char`.`id`
INNER JOIN `dribbling` AS `dri` 
ON         `dri`.`id` = `char`.`id`
INNER JOIN `defending` AS `def` 
ON         `def`.`id` = `char`.`id`
INNER JOIN `physical` AS `phy` 
ON         `phy`.`id` = `char`.`id`          
WHERE FIELD(`char`.`Position`, "CB")
```

This query takes about 1.5 seconds (don't know if this is normal speed or fast/slow). Can I optimize this query to get it faster? If so maybe some of you could tell me the way to do this?!

Here is the explain query:

[image]

Hope there is someone who can help me ;)

Edit:
Show Create for the Joins:
Club

```
    CREATE TABLE `club` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `logo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `league` int(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `league` (`league`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113148 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

League

```
CREATE TABLE `league` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `abbrname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `logo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2119 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Nation

```
CREATE TABLE `nation` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `logo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=220 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Card

```
CREATE TABLE `card` (`id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` enum('TotY','TotS','Legend','RB','Hero','iMotM','MotM','TotW','Green','Gold','Gold Nonrare','Silver','Silver Nonrare','Bronze','Bronze Nonrare') NOT NULL,
 `logo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Pace

```
CREATE TABLE `pace` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pace` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `acceleration` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `sprint_speed` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `pace` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `player` (`pace`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Defending

```
CREATE TABLE `defending` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `defending` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `interceptions` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `heading` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `marking` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `standing_tackle` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `sliding_tackle` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `defending` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `player` (`defending`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Dribbling

```
CREATE TABLE `dribbling` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dribbling` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `agility` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `balance` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `reactions` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `ball_control` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `dribblings` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `dribbling` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `player` (`dribbling`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Shooting

```
CREATE TABLE `shooting` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `shooting` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `positioning` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `finishing` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `shot_power` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `long_shots` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `volleys` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `penalties` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `shooting` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `player` (`shooting`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Physical

```
CREATE TABLE `physical` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `physical` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `jumping` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `stamina` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `strength` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aggression` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `physical` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `player` (`physical`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Passing

```
CREATE TABLE `passing` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `passing` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `vision` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `crossing` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `free_kick` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `short_passing` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `long_passing` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `curve` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `passing` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `player` (`passing`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Characteristics

```
CREATE TABLE `characteristics` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `firstname` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `commonname` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `height` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
 `nation` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `club` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `league` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `picture` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `position` enum('GK','RWB','RB','CB','LB','LWB','CDM','RM','CM','LM','CAM','RW','CF','LW','RF','ST','LF') NOT NULL,
 `rating` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `quality` enum('Gold','Silver','Bronze') NOT NULL,
 `color` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `skill` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `weakfoot` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `strongfoot` enum('Right','Left') NOT NULL,
 `workrates` enum('Low / Low','Low / Medium','Low / High','Medium / Low','Medium / Medium','Medium / High','High / Low','High / Medium','High / High') NOT NULL,
 `traits` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `specialities` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Edit 2: 
EXPLAIN when using ´WHERE Position = 'CB' OR Position = 'ST'´. If I write the query without the OR-Part it will be fine, but with multiple parts there is the same slow outcome like before:
[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with all 120k rows once they have been selected?

Comment: I'm using datatables.net serverside, don't need all of these 120k rows, but a faster query, cause the ajax transfer needs 5 secs, which is too long I guess...

Comment: Can you post results of `show create table <table name>` for all tables in the join?

Comment: Did in the edit ;)

Comment: You say you don't need all the 120K rows. So how many rows does the query return? And can you show a sample data of the `char.Position` column?

Comment: And why do you use `WHERE FIELD(char.Position, "CB")`? Why not `WHERE char.Position='CB'` which can use indexes?

Comment: Oh, forgot `characteristics`, will edit it now. 2867 rows will return with this query and I used field, because it could be more than one condition. But with your mention, I could write `char.Position='CB' OR char.Position=..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, consider rewriting your `WHERE`condition. If instead of using a `FIELD` function you use a direct equal comparison, and have an index (`KEY`) on column `Position`, you allow MySQL to use it. As of now, I guess it needs to do a full table scan to retrieve the rows. The other `JOIN` conditions will need to be evaluated in all cases...

You can check a simplified scenario:

```
 CREATE TABLE characteristics
 (
     id integer primary key,
     firstname character varying(100),
     lastname  character varying(100),
     picture character varying(100),
     position character varying(100),
     -- many other columns
     key(position)
 ) ;

 INSERT INTO characteristics 
 VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe', 'pic1', 'CB') ;

 INSERT INTO characteristics 
 VALUES (2, 'Joe', 'Smith', 'pic2', 'A1') ;
```

We make a select using `FIELD` function:

```
 SELECT  
      c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname
 FROM 
     characteristics AS c
 WHERE 
     FIELD(c.position, 'CB') ;
```

```
 id | firstname | lastname
 -: | :-------- | :-------
  1 | John      | Doe
```

This is the execution plan:

```
 EXPLAIN
 SELECT  
      c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname
 FROM 
     characteristics AS c
 WHERE 
    FIELD(c.position, 'CB') ;
```

```
 id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra

 -: | :---------- | :---- | :--- | :------------ | :--- | :------ | :--- | ---: | :----------
  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |    2 | Using where
```

No keys can be used (i.e.: sequential scan of all `characteristics` table)

We check a second time by using an equals comparison:

```
 SELECT  
      c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname
 FROM 
     characteristics AS c
 WHERE 
     c.position = 'CB' ;
```

We get the same result:

```
 id | firstname | lastname
 -: | :-------- | :-------
  1 | John      | Doe
```

But the execution plan is different:

```
 EXPLAIN
 SELECT  
      c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname
 FROM 
     characteristics AS c
 WHERE 
     c.position = 'CB' ;
```

```
 id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra

 -: | :---------- | :---- | :--- | :------------ | :------- | :------ | :---- | ---: | :--------------------
  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | position      | position | 103     | const |    1 | Using index condition
```

You can check everything at:

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d6461a47299d6fdb7d05b17c4c62794f)*

After you've made this change, consider whether you actually need to further optimize your query. [For instance: do you actually **need** the information of all 11 tables in all cases?]

Comment: Thanks for the response, like a wrote in my comment, I was focused on a multiple selection e.g. Position=CB and =something else, so I choose field, but I can do it with multiple wheres. But it's nice to have an visual overview to get the different ;)

Comment: `WHERE position = 'CB' OR position = 'AD' OR ...` or `WHERE position IN ('CB', 'AD', ...)` to be more concise.

Comment: AFAIK: Using a function `FIELD(x, y)` prevents MySQL from using an index. Latest versions would use it in both the `IN` and =x OR =y situations. Obviously, optimizing a query depends on several factors, an important one of which is the *specific* `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So I tried to use ´WHERE position = 'CB' OR position = 'ST'´ and get the edited EXPLAIN above in the question. If I do a where with more than one position ´type = all´, ´key=null´ and ´ref=null´ too. Shouldn't it be a specific key and not null?

Answer (score 0):

(To long for a comment.)

Do *not* make multiple tables, each with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and then `JOIN` on those ids.  If they ever get out of sync, your data set will be irrecoverably hosed.

In your case, probably `characteristics` should have the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

It is *usually* poor practice to have multiple tables in a 1:1 relation.  You seem to have 7 such tables.  Either combine them into a single table, or somehow justify the split.  That will cut down on the number of `JOINs`, which will speed up the query.

`INT(2)` and `INT(5)` are identical.  Each allows values up to 2 billion.  An `INT` always takes 4 bytes.  Probably want `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte, values 0..255) and `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, 0..65K).  Saving space will help the speed some.

Once you have changed `WHERE FIELD(char.Position, "CB")` to `WHERE char.Position IN ('CB')` (as others have mentioned), the explain plan will start with `char` instead of `pas`.

It does not make sense to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in a query that does not have a `LIMIT` clause.  Simply count the number of rows in the resultset.

Is 1.5 seconds fast or slow for 15K rows returned?  Quote possibly that is the time it takes to shovel several megabytes out of the MySQL server, across the network, and into the client.  What will you do with the results?  If you display it on a web page, it will be unwieldy.